# Why doesn't alt+F4 close cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

In windows, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> does not close cmd (As in: <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, cmd, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

How different is the command window from a normal window?

Comment: There are some third-party hotkey handling programs out there. Some should be able to intercept Alt-F4 only for the relevant command-prompt windows, and use an alternative shutdown (e.g. type "exit", or click the close button, or use the system menu "close" option). Obviously, you should be aware of the possible downside (see Jeffs answer). Sorry, I can't make a recommendation.

Comment: Related: [Is there a Keyboard shortcut to close a Command Prompt window?](http://superuser.com/questions/289460/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-close-a-command-prompt-window)

Comment: you can use `Alt+Space` -> `C` to close it.

Answer (score 18):

The command window uses those key combination for varies applications within the dos emulating window. If Alt-F4 closed the window, it may be impossible to use certain utilities.  If you want a keyboard only fix just type `exit` to quit.

Comment: what certain utilities ? Alt-F4 close almost all the windows in NT Systems, then why command prompt is an exception ?

Comment: Applications before Windows NT in DOS. I remember one game where Alt+F4 brought up the save menu for a game (Wing Commander Armada I believe). Since this is designed to Emulate(or display) DOS it must accept this key combination and not close so these apps can receive the command.

Comment: oh.. Okay... So Microsoft must be still using that combination for some functionality, otherwise they must have provided support by now.

Answer (score 15):

On the other hand, if you are looking to have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> close the console window, you can use the following [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) script:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
    !F4::WinClose, A

#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> sends the program with focus the [`WM_CLOSE` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632617(VS.85).aspx).

So, the `cmd` program is either intentionally configured to ignore `WM_CLOSE` messages, or possibly doesn't process any messages at all.

Comment: This does not entirely apply to Win32 Console windows - they're owned by `conhost` (earlier - by `csrss`), and console applications handle it differently.

Comment: @grawity, duly noted, thanks. But it sounds like that could be the start of the real answer to the question.

Comment: @grawity - I thought within windows, there was still a WM_CLOSE message handled as part of the console program. Not that it makes much difference, though - this is an answer for programmers working on the source of cmd.exe, not for users curious about the design rationale.

Comment: As you can see with iglvzx’s answer, consoles do indeed close in response to `WM_CLOSE`.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows 10 Command Prompt Can Be Closed using ALT+F4 Hotkey](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-cmd-prompt-close-alt-f4-hotkey/) claims that this problem affects only Windows up to 8.1.

> Windows 10 Command Prompt duly responds to ALT+F4

It also mentions that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> can be **disabled** in Windows 10 to mimick the old behaviour by creating a registry key `REG_DWORD` `AllowAltF4Close` set to `0` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`.

Comment: Unfortunately, switching to windows 10 fixes only cmd windows. Powershell ones still ignore ALT+F4.

Comment: just use Windows Terminal and press Ctrl+Shift+W. It works for any shells running in that terminal including cmd, powershell, bash, zsh... There's no reason to use the old conhost.exe terminal anymore because Windows Terminal is vastly better, faster and much more configurable

Comment: What is a Windows Terminal? How do I know what terminal I run? But I see `Ctrl+Shift+W` doesn't close old cmd windows nor new powershell windows. Does windows have a third terminal program that it uses for nothing by default?

Comment: It's the [new open sourced terminal from MS](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal) which is much faster due to hardware acceleration rendering, and more functional. [What is Windows Terminal?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/). Windows 10 only has 1 terminal which is conhost.exe but Windows Terminal can be installed and selected to be the default terminal. Windows 11 uses Windows Terminal by default