# Is there a Keyboard shortcut to close a Command Prompt window?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut to close the Command Prompt window in Windows 7? `Alt+F4` does not seem to work on a Command Prompt window.

I close it right now by typing `exit` and **Enter** at the prompt. Hoping there is a shorter trick.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>
- Create an alias using *doskey*: `doskey x=exit`

Comment: That is not actually a keyboard shortcut.  That is just accessing the menu using the keyboard.

Answer (score 8):

Wrap CMD in [**Console2**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), which would give you CTRL+W to close tabs and ALT+F4 to exit.  You will also be able to use CTRL+V to Paste, if you wish, which is one of the main reasons I use it.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an autohotkey script that'll do it.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
^w::
Send,{LAlt Down}{Space Down}{Space Up}{LAlt Up}{c Down}
return
#IfWinActive
```

It just sends <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> to the window when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> is hit (if it's a command prompt).

Answer (score 3):

It depends from your choice of command interpreter.  This is, of course, because it is your command interpreter that is (largely) determining how TUI command-line editing works.

If you're using [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tcmdledes.htm), for example, an autoexecuting keystroke alias that does exactly this (and that doesn't suffer from the global hotkey problems mentioned in other answers) is simplicity itself to set up using [the `ALIAS` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/alias.htm):

```
alias @@f4=*exit
```

With `bash` one could do the same thing, using the `bind` built-in command, to bind the key sequence for the <kbd>Alt-F4</kbd> key to the string `exit\n`.  The tricky part is working out what key sequence <kbd>Alt-F4</kbd> generates (from the point of view of `bash`, at least) this week.

If you are running your command interpreter within Take Command, [closing the current command tab is done with <kbd>Ctrl+F4</kbd>](http://jpsoft.com./help/keyboard_shortcuts.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a tool such as AutoHotKey to build a shortcut that would close the window. Or create a shortcut that runs a command using tskill to find all cmd windows and close them. That would cause problems if you ever use more than once CMD window at a time and want to close them only selectively.