# Equivalent to ^D (in bash) for cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there an equivalent key-stroke for exiting a command prompt on Windows (launched via Start->Run : cmd) to the bash standby of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> to prevent needing to type `exit` to leave the shell?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on *nix generates a EOF, which various shells interpret as running `exit`. The equivalent for EOF on Windows is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, but cmd.exe does not interpret this specially when typed at the prompt.

Comment: With most modern shells, the terminal is not in canonical input mode when the shell is interactively accepting input, and `Ctrl+D` is in fact just an ordinary character and **not** an EOF special character.  Shells bind `Ctrl+D` to a GNU Readline or ZLE action that exits (but only if the line editing buffer is empty) so the behaviour is _mostly_ the same result.  But `Ctrl+D` is **not** EOF with modern shells, just an ordinary control character.  The behaviour when the editing buffer is not empty is markedly different to what happens with an EOF special character.

Comment: Indeed, the nearest Windows NT equivalent to what `bash` et al. are _actually_ doing is a [TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tcmdledes.htm) autoexecuting keyboard alias, such as [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/289460#289509), where _the command interpreter_ (not the console) recognizes the _ordinary keystroke combination_ `ALT+F4` during line editing and executes the built-in `exit` command in response.

Comment: @JdeBP Going off [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110248/169115) as the starting point, I just tested this with bash 4.4.12 and `stty -a` returns `icanon` (i.e. not `-icanon`). Is your comment `With most modern shells, the terminal is not in canonical input mode when the shell is interactively accepting input` really statistically correct at this point of time?

Comment: @levantpied The tty is `icanon` because Bash sets it *for* `stty -a` (like for any command, e.g. `cat`). When `stty` runs, it's not "when the shell is interactively accepting input". Once `stty` exits, Bash sets the tty back to `-icanon` *for itself*. This is "when the shell is interactively accepting input". To see this `-icanon` Bash sets for itself, you need to run `stty -a` from elsewhere (e.g. `stty -F /dev/pts/5 -a` from another console).

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>. Then, <kbd>C</kbd>.

- (Well, that works on my system, where "C" chooses the option called "close".  Some variation may be needed, as discussed further, later in this answer.)

Yeah, it's a bit slower than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>. But this is the answer to exactly what you're asking for: the built-in equivalent key stroke sequence that lets you exit the prompt without needing to type the `exit` command. No third party software needed.

This may not work absolutely identical to bash: bash will only logout on an empty command line. In Windows, this can close the window, even if you've already typed a partial command on it.

Some more notes about variations:

- Note that a variation might be <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> (pop up Windows context menu), then <kbd>up arrow</kbd> (choose bottom option, which might often be Close/Exit), and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (to choose the highlighted menu option).

  - Naturally, whether a specific keystroke sequence works with a specific program is a detail that can potentially vary between different software programs and, as noted by Richard's comment, different variations (such as different-language release versions).  However, something like that is likely to be an available option for many programs.
- The information mentioned here will work with many pieces of software designed to run in Microsoft Windows (including software bundled in with the operating system, and third party software), but, even so, surely carefully proceeding and testing is recommended before counting on very specific behavior.

  - That said, I accept Richard Neumann's helpful feedback (in a comment to this answer), which is why this answer has been edited to include some information about potential variations.

Comment: This is a locale-dependent answer. Alt+Space opens the Window's context menu and C is then the shortcut so close the window when running with English locale. On my German system it's actually an S(chließen) that I have to press.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Thank you

Comment: A rather locale-independent shortcut would be Alt-F4 which simply closes the window.

Answer (score 7):

Fixed autohotkey approach. (I cannot add a comment.)

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
  ^d::
    ; First send ESC, in case we're in select mode.
    Send {Esc}{Esc}exit{Enter}
#IfWinActive
```

##### Update 2022-10-04

@RichardNeumann wrote it does not work, so checked my own files, it still does. But I do have another code example:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass

^d::Send, exit {Enter}

#IfWinActive
```

Works as for `cmd.exe` and for `powershell`.

Comment: That's a very good solution.

Comment: I used to use this solution for months until I regularly had to connect to a host with screen, and every time I try to detach from a session, I end up sending "e" to the session and write "xit" instead. It was so frustrating I ended up giving up on the AHK hack.

Comment: Here's a nice hack: If you change `exit` to `exit()` Ctrl+D  works for the `python` REPL inside `cmd` too. `cmd` doesn't seem to mind the `()` after `exit`.

Comment: This does not work on Windows 10. However `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key ctrl+d -Function ViExit` does.

Comment: @RichardNeumann, thanx for sharing this. Checked, it still does. Please latest code. By the way, your command belongs to `powershell`. How it will work for `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Apologies, I thought this was supposed to be a Powershell script. I did not realize that `Autohotkey` referred to some third-party software.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, I use it a lot for some tricks like this. Recommended ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [DOSKEY](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-macros-with-the-doskey-utility-in-windows-nt/5755589) to create macros in CMD.exe.

To create a macro type:

```
DOSKEY [macroname]=[command(s)]
```

That way you can bind a key to another command.

Example:

```
DOSKEY e=exit
```

would bind `e` to the `exit` command, so when you input an `e` to the prompt it would be like you input an `exit`

I'm not sure if you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>$n</kbd> combinations as macros though

Comment: Most control characters work okay (except those already handled by the console, of course). But `cmd` just interprets them as normal commands, waiting for `Enter` to be pressed, so there is no advantage of aliasing Ctrl-Z versus just `e` or `x`.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10 using the old `conhost.exe` terminal the equivalent is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>! The option is controlled by the registry key [AllowAltF4Close](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/) and is enabled by default. See [Command prompt in Windows 10 can be closed by Alt+F4](https://winaero.com/command-prompt-in-windows-10-can-be-closed-by-altf4/) for how to disable it (which is what you *don't* want)

In case of [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal) it's even easier, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to [close the current tab/pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/panes). It'll work for any shells like cmd, powershell, bash... Windows Terminal is vastly better, faster, more performant, supports Unicode and POSIX ANSI sequences fully, and completely configurable so there's no reason to use the old `conhost.exe` terminal anymore. Even Windows 11 made Windows Terminal the default console

Answer (score 2):

There is now an open source project called clink at http://code.google.com/p/clink/ (edit: it moved to http://mridgers.github.io/clink/) - it brings Unix readline functionality to the Windows command prompt.

It supports most functionality including command-line editing, history search, tab completion along with completion scripts, etc. Well worth checking out, makes cmd suck much less. ;]

Answer (score 1):

Windows Terminal now lets you choose what keyboard shortcut you want for "close tab".

I'd recommend switching to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same effect with this [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) snippet:

```
; Close Command Prompt when pressing Ctrl+D
#IfWinActive, Command Prompt$
  ^d::
    ; First send ESC, in case we're in select mode.
    Send {Esc}{Esc}exit{Enter}
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, any clues why?

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan: I've been told, depending on how you start Command Prompt, the window title can be different from what I used in this script. The second line might need adjustments depending on your preference.